# c# WebRequest UriFormatException

Tags: c#, webrequest

I currently have the below code, that throws an exception: UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The Authority/Host could not be parsed. on the WebRequest.Create line.  What am I doing wrong?

```
        var path = "http:/mwo.smurfy-net.de/api/oauth2/token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=1&client_secret=2";
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(path);
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        var response = request.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't it be double slashes:

```
var path = "http://mwo.smurfy-net.de/api/oauth2/token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=1&client_secret=2";
```

Comment: o.O  Thank you, knew it was something silly.  Can't believe I missed that for 30 minutes :/